# How to count unique values in aggregation in koalas

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas

New to koalas and trying to do something really basic. I am simply trying to count the unique values in a column in an aggregation. In pandas I would do:

```
df.groupby('columnname').agg({'column_i_want_count_of_unique_values' : pd.Series.nunique})
```

But for example `ks.Series.nunique` doesn't work and 'count' also does not seem to give the right answer.

Pretty frustrating for something so simple and common, and annoying that I can't seem to find it in the documentation for something that bills itself as porting pandas to spark.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`nunique`](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.groupby.GroupBy.nunique.html)

```
df.groupby('columnname')['column_i_want_count_of_unique_values'].nunique()
```

Comment: I get the error: 
TypeError: 'GroupedData' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What version of koalas are you using? The syntax should be correct, as it's the same as in their documentation

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the correct syntax is:

```
df.groupby('columnname').agg({'column_i_want_count_of_unique_values' : 'nunique'})
```

Source: https://github.com/databricks/koalas/pull/512

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for me.. I get: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Unable to get Function: MetaException(message:User: arn:aws:sts::022565123368:assumed-role/databricks_s3_ads/i-09d08eb4c2f46725e is not authorized to perform: glue:GetUserDefinedFunction on resource: arn:aws:glue:ap-southeast-2:022565123368:userDefinedFunction/default/nunique (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: f793200f-6c7c-4d11-a76b-850aa59f1c9f)));

Comment: that's probably an unrelated error... looks like some access denied problem

Comment: thats a bit wierd, because df.groupby('columnname').agg({'column_i_want_count_of_unique_values' : 'count'}) does something. So I don't really get what kind of access I am getting denied from